No objects to concatenate
When i run code foe web crawler in jupyter it is worked completely but when I add this code in data bricks it cerate error for some pin code. what is issue ?
I am scrap information for dealers but it is not work for some pincode

Please read How do I ask a good question? and revise your post based on it and what you see in questions that get good engagement and solutions. As written now, it just looks like you need to troubleshoot what is different about the networks where you are working & communication with the sites you are accessing from there. And if there are limitations you may not be able to perform the same tasks in all the places you work, without some changes. Without details provided by you, it is doubtful you'll receive much actionable guidance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
